# Catching a textbox value which is stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my controller.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public static string commString = "";

    public HomeController()
    {
      FWUtility.connString = "data source=.;initial catalog=northwind;uid=sa;password=123";
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return View();
    }

    public static DataTable GetData(string customerID)
    {
      string strFilter = "'" + customerID + "%'";
      commString = "select * from customers where CustomerID like " + strFilter;
      return FWUtility.GetDataTable(commString);
    }
```

This is the view.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function buttonClick() {
            var value = $('#text1').val();
            alert('@HomeController.GetData("D").Rows.Count.ToString()');
        }
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="text1" value="A" />
    <input type="text" id="text2" />
    <input type="button" value="Show" id="button1" onclick="buttonClick()" />
```

I want to catch the value which is stored in the textbox and display it in the alert box, where I have mentioned **"D"**. In my controller I have a sql query assigned.And here I am calling the controller. My out put will be suppose I put "A" inside the text box and click the button, i will get the count of all the names starting with letter "A". Like this

Comment: If I am getting you right, you want to use the value variable in place of "D"?

Comment: Or ... do you want to call the HomeController to get data based on the value of the #text1?

Comment: If that is the case then try this,
alert('@HomeController.GetData("' + value + '").Rows.Count.ToString()');

Comment: @freedomn-m,yes you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, done it at last. Here is the solution.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonClick() {
        var value = $('#text1').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '../Home/GetData',
            method: 'POST',
            data: { customerID: value },
            success: function (data) {
                result = data;
                alert(result);
            },
        });
    }
</script>
<input type="text" id="text1" value="A" />
<input type="button" value="Show" id="button1" onclick="buttonClick()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question, but assuming you want more than a simple `alert(value)`, then:

I suggest that you add an additional action to go with the `GetData` function to return row count directly:

```
public ActionResult GetDataRowCount(string id)
{
    var count = GetData(id).Rows.Count;
    return new JsonResult
               {
                   Data = new { count },
                   JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
               };

}
```

then you can use jquery ajax to get this value from the controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonClick() {
        var value = $('#text1').val();

        $.get({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDataRowCount", "Home")',
            data: { id = value }, 
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result.count);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<input type="text" id="text1" value="A" />
<input type="button" value="Show" id="button1" onclick="buttonClick()" />
```